# Convert caption tag to figure tag

Tags: c#, php, regex, html

I want to convert this: (from Wordpress)

```
[caption id="attachment_5433" align="aligncenter" width="413"]
    <a href="http://baicadicungnamthang.net/uploads/2012/02/NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh" src="http://baicadicungnamthang.net/uploads/2012/02/NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh.jpg" alt="NSƯT Tuyết Thanh" width="413" height="551"></a>NSƯT Tuyết Thanh
[/caption]
```

to this: (html5)

```
<figure>
    <a href="http://baicadicungnamthang.net/uploads/2012/02/NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh" src="http://baicadicungnamthang.net/uploads/2012/02/NSUT-Tuyet-Thanh.jpg" alt="NSƯT Tuyết Thanh" width="413" height="551"></a>
    <figcaption>NSUT Tuyết Thanh</figcaption>
</figure>
```

How to do it by PHP or C#?

Comment: Start by reading the [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) documentation.

Comment: This goes hand-in-hand with your other question about the image in the caption ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$subject = preg_replace(
'/\[caption[\s]{0,}(.*?)\][\s]{0,}(<a[\s]{0,}.*?<\/a>)[\s]{0,}(.*?)\[\/caption\]/ims', 
'<figure $1> $2 <figcaption>$3</figcaption> </figure>',
$subject);
```

Where $subject is having the actual string of [caption] to [/caption]